# System.UnexpectedException: Invalid parameter value for parameter "Decryption Exception"

Tags: callout, error

I tried to execute some code in a sandbox and I got an odd error message:

> System.UnexpectedException: Invalid parameter value '****' for
>   parameter "Decryption Exception".

Looks like it happened immediately following a callout attempt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the callout was using a Named Credential with "Named Principle - Password Authentication".  I guess when SF created the sandbox it doesn't properly copy over the password.

I updated the password and now it works...