# Authenticate AWS Transcribe Service from apex

Tags: apex, authentication, aws

We are trying to use AWS [Transcribe](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/) service to convert voice to text. As first step we are trying to authenticate to AWS using the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html) they have provided. Whatever we do we end up with the below error.

```
{"__type":"InvalidSignatureException","message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}
```

We are able to successfully call transcribe service from postman and named credentials doesn't work.

Below is our apex code:

```
public class S3Test1 {

   // public static HttpRequest createAWSRequest(String method, String service, String host, String region, String endpoint, String contentType, String requestJson) {
    public static void createAWSRequest() { 
        String method = 'POST';
        String service = 'transcribe';
        String host = 'transcribe.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';
        String region = 'us-west-2';
        String endpoint = 'https://transcribe.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/';
        String contentType = 'application/x-amz-json-1.1';
        String requestJson ='{"LanguageCode": "en-US","Media": {"MediaFileUri": "S3 audio file link"},"MediaFormat": "mp4","MediaSampleRateHertz": 44100,"TranscriptionJobName": "SampleRestJob7"}';
        String amzDate = system.Now().format('yyyyMMdd')+ 'T' + system.Now().formatGMT('HHmmss') + 'Z';
        String dateStamp = system.Now().format('yyyyMMdd');
        String accessKey = 'our access key';
        String secretKey = 'our secret key';

        String canonical_headers = 'content-type:' + contentType + '\n' + 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'+'x-amz-target:'+'Transcribe.StartTranscriptionJob' + '\n';
        String signedHeaders = 'content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target';
        Blob payloadHash = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(requestJson));
        String hexpayload = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(payloadHash);

        String canonicalRequest = method +'\n'+ canonical_headers + '\n' + signedHeaders + '\n' + hexpayload; 
      //   String hexcanonicalrequest = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(canonicalRequest);

        //TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN
         String algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
        String credentialScope = dateStamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request';
        String stringToSign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzDate + '\n' +  credentialScope + '\n' +  EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(canonicalRequest)));
        system.debug('stringToSign' + stringToSign);
         Blob signingkey = getSignatureKey(secretKey, dateStamp, region, service);
         Blob signature = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), signingkey);
        String hexSignature = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(signature);

        //TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST
        String authorizationHeader = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + accessKey + '/' + credentialScope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signedHeaders + ', ' + 'Signature=' + hexSignature;
         HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
        httpReq.setMethod(method);
        httpReq.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        httpReq.setBody(requestJson);
        httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
        httpReq.setHeader('host', host);
        httpReq.setHeader('x-amz-date', amzDate);
        httpReq.setHeader('x-amz-target', 'Transcribe.StartTranscriptionJob');
        httpReq.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
          HTTPResponse response = new HTTPResponse();
       Http http = new Http();   
       response = http.send(httpReq);
        system.debug(response);
        system.debug(response.getbody());

        if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
            System.debug('Request Successful');
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        AWSTranscribeResponseWrapper resWrapper = (AWSTranscribeResponseWrapper)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), AWSTranscribeResponseWrapper.class);
        System.debug(resWrapper);
       // System.debug(resWrapper.Transcript.TranscriptFileUri);
        }

    }

    public Static Blob sign(Blob key, String msg) {
        return Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueof(EncodingUtil.urlEncode(msg, 'UTF-8')), key); // hmac.new(key, msg.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    }

    public static Blob getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) {
      Blob kDate = sign(Blob.valueOf('AWS4' + key), dateStamp);
        Blob kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName);
        Blob kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName);
        Blob kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request');
        return kSigning;
    }
}
```

Any Inputs on what is wrong with the code would be super helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Named credential AWS Signature V4 - incorrect signature](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279138/named-credential-aws-signature-v4-incorrect-signature)

Comment: No.Already checked that, It did not work.The link is to authenticate S3 whereas i am trying to authenticate transcribe service. there are subtle differences.

Comment: @sfdcfox, it is check the method getSignatureKey and sign at the end. Am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I see that now. I'm comparing your code to mine to see where the problem is. I know mine works, we use it currently.

Comment: Here's the link again, just realized I deleted it. https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/92cf05807ac4becbd21f

Comment: Can I ask you to try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/dfc90371ea3bf8385581c8b37df3449a) plus the previous code? It should give you a baseline to start from to diagnose this thing. Your code is rather difficult to parse all at once. I'll keep looking in the meantime.

Comment: @RedDevil AWS v4 signature algorithm is the same across all AWS services that use it, Named Credential implements it correctly. Our customers use Named Cred + AWS quite a bit.

Comment: @sfdcfox - i wll try your code and let you know

Comment: @sfdcfox - Your code works well, made 2 changes to it, had to change date format to ISO8601 and set content type as amz json. Now i have to reverse engineer to find out whats wrong wtih my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sfdcfox,was able to find the root cause, posting answer for benefit of community

From AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html) below is the format of canonical request

```
CanonicalRequest =
  HTTPRequestMethod + '\n' +
  CanonicalURI + '\n' +
  CanonicalQueryString + '\n' +
  CanonicalHeaders + '\n' +
  SignedHeaders + '\n' +
  HexEncode(Hash(RequestPayload))
```

In our case our request was in the body and we did not have query string so omitted CanonicalURI and CanonicalQueryString  because of which we ran into signature mis-match error.

Guess when we use SHA 256 algorithm to generate digest, every character matters which is why this error happened.

1. if the URI is blank just use a forward slash `'/'`
2. if query string is null just instantiate a empty query string as
   part of the canonical request.
3. For AWS transcribe the content type has to be `application/x-amz-json-1.1` both in the header and part of canonical headers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a name credential AWS_Transcribe with AWS S4 signature version and use the following code-

```java
public static void createAWSCallTranscribeRequest() { 
        String method = 'POST';       
        String endpoint = 'callout:AWS_Transcribe/';
        String contentType = 'application/x-amz-json-1.1';
        String requestJson ='{"LanguageCode": "en-US","Media": {"MediaFileUri": "url"},"MediaFormat": "wav","TranscriptionJobName": "TestTranscribe"}';
        
        HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
        httpReq.setMethod(method);
        httpReq.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        httpReq.setBody(requestJson);
        httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
        
        httpReq.setHeader('x-amz-target', 'Transcribe.StartTranscriptionJob');
        
       HTTPResponse response = new HTTPResponse();
       Http http = new Http();   
       response = http.send(httpReq);
        system.debug(response);
        system.debug(response.getbody());

        if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
            System.debug('Request Successful');
            System.debug(response.getBody());
       
        }

    }
```