# StatusCode 405 when uploading JSON objects to S3 using APEX

Tags: apex, rest-api, amazon-s3

I have a class that should invoke a web request to S3 to upload a JSON object, but I received the following error

```
Response from s3 System.HttpResponse[Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405]
```

```
20:57:04:000 USER_DEBUG <Error><Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code><Message>The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message><Method>PUT</Method></Error>
```

I checked these articles [1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305862/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-using-apex) & [2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279138/accessing-aws-s3-via-a-rest-api-apex-callout-with-a-named-credential) but still couldn't resolve my problem.

Below is the code;

```
public class awsBucketManager{

    @future(callout = true)
    public static void requestAPItoS3(String body, String country){

        Blob JSONBodyBlob = Blob.valueOf(body);
        String attachmentBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(JSONBodyBlob);
        String formattedDateString = Datetime.now().formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');
        String key = 'xxxxx'; //key
        String secret = 'xxxxxx'; //secret
        String bucketname = 'bucket-name-use1';
        String host = 's3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
        String method = 'PUT';
        String fileType = 'text/json';

        HttpRequest awsReq = new HttpRequest();
        awsReq.setMethod('PUT');
        awsReq.setEndpoint('callout:aws_s3_ap');
        awsReq.setHeader('Host', bucketname + '.' + host);
        awsReq.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(attachmentBody.length()));
        awsReq.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8');
        awsReq.setHeader('Content-type', fileType);
        awsReq.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        awsReq.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);
        awsReq.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read-write');
        awsReq.setBodyAsBlob(EncodingUtil.base64Decode(attachmentBody));

        System.debug('******************* Start sending web request to S3 *******************'); 
            
        Http awsHttp = new Http();
        HttpResponse awsResponseMessage = awsHttp.send(awsReq);
        
    }
}
```

I set the named credentials as follow;
[image]

An overview of my S3 bucket config
Block public access (bucket settings) -> it's all off
Bucket policy -> it's empty
ACL -> List Write & Read Write only for the bucket owner

What could be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your endpoint is wrong. You need to specify an action that you're doing, such as:

```
awsReq.setEndpoint('callout:aws_s3_ap/'+awsAction);
```

Where awsAction might be something like:

```
 String awsAction = 'myFile';
```

This would be an action for [PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html), for example.

You need to consult the documentation to determine the correct endpoint to use.