# "Decryption Exception" errors on Named Credential

Tags: oauth2, platform-bug, namedcredentials, auth-provider

I have callouts that use a `Named Credential` and a `Custom Oauth2 Auth Provider` fail with this error response:

> Invalid parameter value "[hidden]" for parameter "Decryption
>   Exception"

A similar error is sometimes shown when I resave the Named Credential

> Unable to Access Page The value of the "Decryption Exception"
>   parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value
>   exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the
>   parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error
>   still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the
>   URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related
>   information.

When I simulate the Oauth Flow and Callout in Postman it always works. **I'm quite sure this is a Platform bug.**

Comment: Is this in a sandbox? Possible duplicate of [System.UnexpectedException: Invalid parameter value for parameter "Decryption Exception"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253985/system-unexpectedexception-invalid-parameter-value-for-parameter-decryption-ex)

Comment: No its a SFDX scratch org and we might see the same symptom but your answer doesn't help me at all.

Comment: How was the named cred created? Manually?  I don't think you can deploy named cred which have encrypted secrets (could be wrong)

Comment: The Named Credential and the Auth Provider is created by Apex code using Metadata API a mechanism which worked like a charm before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was that the `OAuth` `Access Token` returned by our own [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) AuthServer returned was too complex, lengthy. Salesforce is currently not able to handle it. This was assessed and confirmed by Salesforce.com. They just used https://jwt.io/ to decyper one of our acccess tokens an saw a lot of useless stuff in there.

[image]

**By reducing access_token size (remove useless waste) we could fix the problem.**

Besides that, the team at Salesforce responsible for Named Credentials will try to allow longer access tokens from **Spring '20** on. #SafeHarbor

Comment: Asking two years later: Was this ever solved on the platform side? :)